# nodejs mysql amazing row duplicates

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets

I have problem for node.js.

I read data for socket, using `dgram.createSocket('udp4')`.
I parse data and write to mysql db (use https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) with code:

```
var result = {
                  CarID: "0094455",
                  Lat: 55.0405,
                  Lon: 82.981,
                  Time: 1373435075
};
connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM lastPosition WHERE CarID = ? ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1',[result.CarID], 
            function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (rows.length) {
            connection.query('UPDATE lastPosition SET ? WHERE CarID = ?', [result, result.CarID]);
          } else {
            connection.query('INSERT INTO lastPosition SET ?', result);
         }
        });
     connection.end();
});
```

The problem is that I see row duplicates in "lastPosition" table for key CarID, although this excludes the code. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you write your update as an answer, and mark it as accepted please?

Comment: verybadalloc, ok, done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it with code:

```
connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
     connection.query('INSERT INTO `lastPosition` SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Lat=VALUES(Lat), Lon=VALUES(Lon), Time=VALUES(Time)', result);
     connection.end();
    });
```

Comment: Nice! Now, after 36 hours, would you be kind enough to accept your own answer? In the meantime, here is my upvote.